# How to update source files for pytest?

Tags: python

pytest appears to be using old source code and failing tests because of it. I'm not sure how to update it.

Test code:

```
from nba_stats import league


class TestLeaders():
    def test_default():
        leaders = league.Leaders()
        print(leaders)
```

Source code (league.py):

```
from nba_stats.nba_api import NbaAPI
from nba_stats import constants


class Leaders:
...
```

When I run `pytest` on my parent directory, I get an error that refers to an old import statement.

```
_____________________________ ERROR collecting test/test_league.py ______________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/mfb/src/nba_stats/test/test_league.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
test_league.py:1: in <module>
    from nba_stats import league
../../../.virtualenvs/nba_stats_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nba_stats/league.py:1: in <module>
    from nba_stats import _api_scrape, _get_json
E   ImportError: cannot import name '_api_scrape'
```

I tried resetting my virtualenvironment and also reinstalling my package via pip. What do I need to do to tell it to see the new import statement and why is this happening?

Edit: Deleting my virtual environment completely and then creating a new one seemed to fix it, but it seems to be a recurring issue with any further source code changes. Surely there must be a way to not have to reset my virtualenvironment each time?

Comment: Is the working directory the same for your main script and the testing script? If that fixes it, you should probably look into refactoring the code so it doesn't rely on that, or perhaps you're OK with that being a requirement.

Comment: `__pycache__` dir present?

Comment: @Grismar no, they are in different directories, but moving them to the same directory doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @ssnobody yes, and I tried deleting it which didn't help

Comment: import sys and check all entries in the sys.path to ensure that your modules (nba_stats?) aren't present .

Comment: @ssnobody doesn't look like they're there

Comment: Re-reading this, I'm kind of confused. Are you saying that ../../../.virtualenvs/nba_stats_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nba_stats/league.py does exist? Because that file appears to be an actual physical file someplace on your system and it appears to actually contain that `cannot import name '_api_scrape'`. Remove the nba_stats directory in `../../../.virtualenvs/nba_stats_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` if you don't want it to be picked up anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you installed that package (possibly as a dependency through something else if not directly) and also have it cloned locally for development. You can look into local editable installs (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs), but personally, I prefer to make the test refer directly to the package under which it is being run, since then it can be used "as-is" after cloning it. Do this by modifying `sys.path` in your `test_league.py`. Ie., assuming it has a structure with the python code under `python/nba_stats`, in the parent directory of `test

```
sys.path = [os.path.join(os.pardir, 'python')] + sys.path
```

at the top of `test_league.py`. This puts your local package up front and `import` will consider it first.

**EDIT:**
Since you tried and it still did not work (please do make sure that the snippet above does point to the local python package as in the actual structure; the above is just a common one but you may have a different structure), here is how you can see which directories are considered in order, and which are eventually selected:

```
python -vv -m pytest -svx
```

You will be able to see if there are spurious directories in sys.path, whether the one tried (as in the snippet above) matches as expected or not, any left-over .pyc files that get picked up, etc.

**EDITv2**: Since you stated that `python -m pytest` works, but `pytest` not, have a look where that `pytest` executable is coming from with `which pytest`. Likely it's a system one that refers to a different `python` then the one in your `virtualenv`. To see which python it picks up, do:

```
cat `which python`
```

and look at the top line.

If that is not the same as what `which python` gives you (with your desired virtualenv activated), you may have to install `pytest` for that current virtualenv (`python -m pip install pytest`).

Comment: I don't think this is it. The package `nba_stats` is only a local package (my own development not available anywhere else) and the above code doesn't work for me to further prove that. I also checked my sys.path and it isn't present there either.

Comment: But your error shows it's being picked up from a 'site-packages' directory: `./../../.virtualenvs/nba_stats_dev/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nba_stats/league.py:`. It only gets there through installation.

Comment: could that be due to listing `nba_stats` in my setup.py under packages? If the solution to my problem is to not install the package, I'm not sure how to prevent that.

Comment: If it's in the setup.py `requirements`, it will be installed, yes, but a package should not list itself, so not sure that I understand? And no, the solution as far as I'm concerned is not to *not* install it (although you could this with the `--editable` option as per the link above): I propose to prepend the directory to the local package to `sys.path` as in the snippet above. If done at the top of `test_league.py`, it guarantees that the local package will be selected, regardless what else is installed, what `$PYTHONPATH` says, etc.

Comment: I'm using --editable, and I tried the above code snippet to no avail.

Comment: Ok so running python -m pytest works, but just pytest by itself gives me the issue. I tried the -vv option, but the output is unruly and I'm not sure what to make of it.